# Linked List Pointer Scope

Tags: java

How come when I create a linked list node, append some data, then move the head in another method, the head stays the same in the callee method?

For example:

```
public static void append(Node n, int d) {
    while (n.next != null) {
        n = n.next;
    }

    n.next = new Node(d);
}

public static void test(Node n) {
    n = n.next;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node head = new Node(5);
    append(head, 4);
    append(head, 3);

    test(head); //this moves the head to head.next
    //why is head still = 5 after we get here? 
}
```

Comment: Your `test` method doesn't do **anything**.

Comment: head should be passed by reference right? In test, when I move n = n.next, n.data = 4 in that method, but in main, how come 
head.data = 5?

Comment: @MiketheViking90 "head should be passed by reference right?" No, the reference is passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

In the method `append`, the line `n = n.next` won't affect the original node passed as argument, in your case `head`. *Why?* [Because Java is *pass by value*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/2670792). This means that if inside the method, you modify the reference of `head` (which is received as `n` inside the method), it won't affect the original reference. Therefore, `head` will still refering to the same location in memory (the same object).

Also, your method `test` doesn't do anything because you are creating a *local variable*:

```
Node next = ...;
```

and then assigning `n.next` to it. But this variable only exists inside that method, so it won't affect anything outside it.

Comment: "the line n = n.next won't affect the original node n ... n will still refer to the same location in memory". This is highly misleading. That code works perfectly well within the method.

Answer (score 0):

`next` is a property, not a method.  Your `test` method is just grabbing the reference to `n.next`, it is not "moving the head."